# How to determine which Linux i2c adaptor is associated with specific bus

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

I am building a Linux system based on a SoC that has an FPGA. The system has multiple i2c busses based on both "hard" IP and instances of a soft IP that I am implementing in the FPGA.
My attempts to define the order of the adapters in Device Tree are failing.
The [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/i2c/dev-interface.html#:%7E:text=Each%20registered%20i2c%20adapter%20gets,system%20at%20a%20given%20time.) states

> Adapter numbers are assigned somewhat dynamically, so you can not assume much about them. They can even change from one boot to the next.

I can view the adapters list

```
i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c             i2c-ocores                              I2C adapter
i2c-2   i2c             i2c-ocores                              I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c             Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter         I2C adapter
```

or

```
head /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-*/name
==> /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-0/name <==
Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter

==> /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-1/name <==
i2c-ocores

==> /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-2/name <==
i2c-ocores
```

(The above is a simplified example but shows that multiple busses may display same name).

I am looking for an explicit method to assign numbers to the busses (through a Device Tree) or reliable way to detect which adapter is associated with which bus

I tried changing the order and descriptors in the *Device Tree* but that didn't yield results.

Another page at [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.1/i2c/instantiating-devices.html) gives me a hint that what I am looking for may be possible

> Method 1: Declare the I2C devices statically.
> This method is appropriate when the I2C bus is a system bus as is the case for many embedded systems. On such systems, each I2C bus has a number which is known in advance. It is thus possible to pre-declare the I2C devices which live on this bus.

but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar - Disagree with your close vote. This is a border-line topic, but only an embedded developer, typically a SW engineer, has to solve this type of problem. A system admin or end-user never has to deal with this type of issue. IMO this question fits the [4th type of allowed topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which is `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`.

Comment: In that case the question should include the code that they're trying to write that needs to use this information.

Comment: @Barmar has a valid point. I am actually writing a C code that needs to know which bus to address. To make the description of the problem simpler I used utilities output as an example. I will add a code example to comply.

Comment: Look at the symlinks, they point out to the devices on the busses. It's pure Q on how to use sysfs. Has nothing to do with programming (+1 to close it).